# Node.js & amcharts4 - how to integrate and call core.js and charts.js correctly via 'Javascript'

Tags: node.js, amcharts

I just downloaded the new amCharts4 into my node.js app via npm to test it. Wenn installed I find the files chore.js and charts.js in MyNodejsApp/node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4 :

```
MyNodejsApp
_node_modules
 |_@amcharts
  |_amcharts4
   |_charts.js
   |_core.js
  |_amcharts4-geodata
_public
 |_css
  |_styles.css
 |_js
  |_main.js
_views
 |_partials
  |_scripts.ejs
 |_dashboard.ejs
 |_index.ejs     
app.js
```

As you can see I placed my css and js files in folder public. I'm also using ejs and call the files via views/index.ejs and dashboard.ejs. I'm then loading my js files via script.ejs.

script.ejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>

# this worked
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>

# this did not work 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/amcharts/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/amcharts/charts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/amcharts/themes/animated.js"></script>
```

dashboard.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <% include partials/head %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chartdiv"></div>


        <% include partials/script %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where and how do I exactly integrate and call the charts.js and core.js file? I'm assuming also in my script.ejs ? But do I copy & paste charts.js and core.js files in my public/js folder (which didn't work under folder public/js/amcharts)? or how do I integrate and access them?

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/basics/